# Unable to find the users in membership table

Tags: c#

I am inserting a user using membership provider

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipCreateStatus status;
        MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser("chandu1", "P@ssw0rd", "rasdsd@sdsdh.com", "null", "null", true, out status);

        switch(status)
  {
             case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
             Response.Write("User already exists in system.Please select different name and try again");
             break;
             case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail :
             Response.Write("Duplicate Email");
             break;
             case MembershipCreateStatus.Success :
             Response.Write("User has been created successfully");
             break;
    }
```

But i am unable to find the user in the membership table or users table where can i find them?.How membership provider determines in which database it should insert the user,i am new to this can anyone help me?

Comment: What error are you getting? Your question doesn't really match the code snippet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use a ASP.net website, you'll need to look at the Web.Config, if you use an other kind of project you need to take a look at the App.Config

These files are the places where they store the connectionstring to lets say a DB

Part of a web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

As you can see here there is the [connectionstring](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) which will tell the membershipprovider where to look for the Database or file.

next to that there are some Nodes in you Web.Config that tell something about the authentication mode and membershipprovider.

If you want to use the ASP.netDB for saving users/roles take a look at the [Aspnet_regsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx#findingthecorrectversion) command that can be found in the %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\VersionNumber

Here another nice [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of how to create an asp.net MVC2 website using Forms authentication

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Its clearly mentioned on MSDN that sql server is mandatory for default configuration of Membership class. In case you are not using MSSQL in backend then refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa) which will show you how to track datasource.Otherwise open the MSSQL management studio and see what databases are availble,it is suspected that you'll discover schema with  [this name](http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx).

PROBABLITY:Some where I saw that default name in MSSQL is ASPNETDB.